# Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587 on windows server 2016

Tags: java, email, smtp, windows-server-2016

I am trying to send an email from a gmail account from windows server 2016 from a Java application and I get the error : "Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587."

When trying on my local machine, which runs windows 10, the code works perfectly.
I have used mail enable and port 587 is enabled and also used as an alternate port to listen to for SMTP. Also, I configured an inbound rule for this port on windows server. I still have the same error.
Does anyone know what I can do ?

I will also add the code.

```
package email;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class GoogleMail {

    public void sendEmail(String emailContent) {

        final String username = "findyourbets2020@gmail.com";
        final String password = "*********";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("findyourbets2020@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("testemail@gmail.com"));
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            message.setSubject("Application Failed at" + timestamp);
            message.setText(emailContent);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Also, I configured an inbound rule for this port on windows server.*" - I am no expert on Windows administration, so maybe this is open by default. But check that the packages are allowed to leave, i.e. you have a matching outbound rule.

Comment: I tried and it did not work :(

Comment: to me, that error is too vague and an interpretation of what's really hapenning. Use wireshark and see how far it goes. You won't decrypt past the starttls, but at least you will rule out a basic TCP problem if any.

Answer (score 0):

Is that gmail account configured to allow 'unsecure apps'?
You may need to setup an app token to allow such direct connections to gmail.

Comment: yes, it is. this is why it works on my local computer

Comment: ok, so just to be sure, you are using the same token as your desktop mail client or you generated a new token for the relevant user agent that is presented to gmail? IIRC, gmail disabled unsecure apps unless you periodically return to the gmail account via web, or something weird like that. Just saying, check if it works better if you go to the web gmail and generate new app token then use it. A java program is most certainly going to show as a distinct client from regular desktop apps.